# Displaying an image in custom shape and drag effect on konvajs

Tags: konvajs

There is an example posted by [Vanquished Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7073944/vanquished-wombat) on the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71479508/how-to-handle-with-images-overflow-draggable-area-etc-on-konva-js-stage/76223478#76223478)

The example uses the Konva Rect and Konva Image in Konva Group. Is it possible to achieve the same effect using Konva Line (having Points) to draw a custom shape and use fillPatternImage to draw the Image inside it.

Answer (score 1):

In principle it would be possible because inside a custom shape you can use native canvas commands to draw the shape. Therefore you could draw the path then use the same path to defined the clip region, then draw the image. That will give what you describe as your requirement.

Comment: I tried with konvajs but so far it didn't work. https://codepen.io/Faiz-Haque/pen/YzJLMBq

Comment: You removed jquery dependency. This is just for the checkbox listener and not part of Konva or the solution. Add it back in and it all works !!

Comment: Oh, Thanks for pointing out. I just added it. https://codepen.io/Faiz-Haque/pen/YzJLMBq

however, it still looks bit off

Comment: Ah ok - looks like it lost the drag on the image.